# Convergent of integral of $1/x^x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, infinitesimals

I need to prove if this integral converges (on interval $[1,+\infty))$:

$$\int _1^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^x}\;dx$$

Has anybody any idea how to do it?

thank you. 
:)

Comment: For $x>2, x^x > x^2$, so...

Comment: [How to format mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$\frac{1}{x^x}\leq\frac{1}{x^2}\mbox{ for }x\geq 2,\mbox{ and }\frac{1}{x^x}\leq 1\mbox{ for }1\leq x\leq 2.$$
This implies that for any sufficiently large $N$
$$\int _1^{N}\frac{1}{x^x}dx=\int _1^{2}\frac{1}{x^x}dx+\int _2^{N}\frac{1}{x^x}dx
\leq\int _1^{2}dx+\int _2^{N}\frac{1}{x^2}dx
=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{N}.$$
Letting $N\to\infty$, we get
$$\int _1^{N}\frac{1}{x^x}dx\leq\frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: @TravisJ You are absolutely right! I edited my answer.